# C# Use constructor inside if/else

Tags: c#

When I write the code as follows, the `DateTime` object `Ende` does not exist on the line when it calculates milliseconds (according to intellisense). Why is that code incorrect and how do I then use the constructors correctly?

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Take image and analyse for radius
        Capture_Image();
        Measure_Circle();
        //stop timer
        timer2.Stop();
        //Same code as when button13 is clicked
        DateTime Start = DateTime.Now;

        if(DateTime.Now.ToString("tt") == "AM")
        {
            DateTime Ende = new DateTime(Start.Year, Start.Month, Start.Day, 12, 20, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            DateTime Ende = new DateTime(Start.Year, Start.Month, Start.Day + 1, 0, 20, 0);
        }

        int dauer = (int)(Ende - Start).TotalMilliseconds;
        label32.Text = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(dauer+100).ToString();

        label28.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();

        timer2.Interval = dauer;
        timer2.Start();
    }
```

Comment: You can't access variables outside the scope  in which they were declared in..

Comment: declare it outside of the if

Comment: `if (Start.Hour < 12)` should be a little more efficient than converting it to a string and doing a string comparison with `"AM"`

Comment: In fact, you can get rid of the whole `if` thing and use a ternary operator to create the `Ende` date: `DateTime Ende = Start.Date.AddHours(Start.Hour < 12 ? 12 : 24);` This works because the `Date` property returns just the date portion (with the time set to 0), then we can add either `12` or `24` hours to that, depending on whether or not `Start` is before noon.

Answer (score 1):

define `Ende` outside  of if statement and assign it inside. Try like:

```
....
DateTime Ende = new DateTime();
if(DateTime.Now.ToString("tt") == "AM")
{
  Ende = new DateTime(Start.Year, Start.Month, Start.Day, 12, 20, 0);
}
else
{
  Ende = new DateTime(Start.Year, Start.Month, Start.Day + 1, 0, 20, 0);
}
```

Comment: there is not necessary to assign `Ende` a value, it will be overwritten anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This way:

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Take image and analyse for radius
    Capture_Image();
    Measure_Circle();
    //stop timer
    timer2.Stop();
    //Same code as when button13 is clicked
    DateTime Start = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime Ende;
    if(DateTime.Now.ToString("tt") == "AM")
    {
        Ende = new DateTime(Start.Year, Start.Month, Start.Day, 12, 20, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        Ende = new DateTime(Start.Year, Start.Month, Start.Day + 1, 0, 20, 0);
    }

    int dauer = (int)(Ende - Start).TotalMilliseconds;
    label32.Text = DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(dauer+100).ToString();

    label28.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();

    timer2.Interval = dauer;
    timer2.Start();
}
```

Just declare `DateTime Ende;` before the if statements. This error happens because of the **variable scope**.